# How do I install SQL Server Express 2014 in Vagrant without a Desktop?

Tags: sql-server, vagrant, windows-server-2012-r2, chocolatey

I'd like to have Vagrant bring up a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine and install [SQL Server 2014 Express](https://chocolatey.org/packages/MsSqlServer2014Express) as part of the provisioning.  I've got chocolatey installed on the machine and have vagrant running a powershell file like this:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./dev-tools.ps1"
```

And a simple `choco install mssqlserver2014express -y` in that powershell script.  It runs the script, it looks like the SQL installer doesn't like being run without a display:

```
==> default: The following error occurred:
==> default:
==> default: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is 
not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify 
the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
notification from a service application.
==> default:
==> default: Error result: -2146233079
==> default: Result facility code: 19
==> default: Result error code: 5385
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this as part of provisioning a windows box?

Comment: Request to the package author(s): https://chocolatey.org/packages/MsSqlServer2014Express#comment-1860401744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to go back to the maintainers of the package and ask them if they can make the sql server installer completely silent. Share this stack overflow post with them.

Comment: I've put in comments with the maintainer mentioning that the package should run the installer with /Q instead of /QS.  Hopefully they will consider it.

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing.  I think Anthony Matsrean's answer is a good workaround otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, you might try turning on the GUI. Windows Server 2012 R2 still has a GUI, by default, right? I assume you're using the VirtualBox provider since you didn't specify otherwise.

Add this to your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html

Comment: This is a valuable workaround, but in the long run I think that getting the package fixed is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to adapt (or just use) https://github.com/leezu/vagrant-mssql-express/